why is the underbrace when writing equation different?
why is it that the inderbraces are appearing broken but continuous in other. even though i have written the same exact code but just in two different documents.
H^{\mathrm{SSH}} =  \underbrace{\frac{v}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{N} \sigma_{2j-1}^{xx}}_{X_{v}}
+ \underbrace{\frac{v}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{N} \sigma_{2j-1}^{yy}}_{Y_{v}}
+ \underbrace{\frac{w}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \sigma_{2j}^{xx}}_{X_{w}}
+ \underbrace{\frac{w}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \sigma_{2j}^{yy}}_{Y_{w}}

Both i have written the same code, but why is it broken in one document. am i missing some packages? i checked though there are no extra packages



Welcome! Please make a small but complete example.

Apparently used fonts are not the same in the both cases. You need provide MWEs (Minimal Working Examples), which produced showed results.

Loading the amsmath package would appear to be a good idea.
